# Unexpected result of regexp replace

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this

```
>> 'Tøjstørrelse'.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/g, '_');
```

result in

```
"_T__j_s_t__r_r_e_l_s_e_"
```

and not

```
"Tjstrrelse"
```

as I would expect ?

UPDATE: This question is for me to understand the behaviour. I know that `'Tøjstørrelse'.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, '_');` gives the desired result.

Comment: Regarding your update: is my explanation enough or is there still a part that you don't understand?

Comment: No - I think I get it now. Thanks for all the input guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `[^A-Za-z0-9]*` is matching the empty string before every single non matching character. replace the `*` with `+` and it will work

`*` is equivalent to `{0,}` means match 0 or more of the previous construct ==> 0 occurrences means it will match every time the empty string when there is no char to match!

`+` is equivalent to `{1,}` means it requires at least one occurrence to match.

```
'Tøjstørrelse'.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, '_');
```

This will result in

```
T_jst_rrelse
```

Answer (score 1):

`[^A-Za-z0-9]*` can match zero characterless, and that can be found anywhere.

You want to use + `[^A-Za-z0-9]*`, or even better `\W+`.
`\w` also matches underscore, but I think that can work for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
'Tøjstørrelse'.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g, '');
```

In fact, the `+` is optional - if you omitted it, it would still work.

**EDIT:** Since have edited your question asking for an explanation, here it is:

`/[^A-Za-z0-9]` will match against anything that is *not* alphanumeric (`^` specifies *not* and the ranges after are OR'd together so it means not {A to Z, a to z or 0 to 9}).

If you include the `+` after, it means "one or more occurence". So for example if there are three non-alphanumeric characters in a row they would be replaced in bulk if you include `+` but replaced one-by-one without - makes no difference to the results.

Comment: That is correct, but what's the harm in replacing nothing with nothing?

Comment: No difference in the results but semantically it seems very wrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
'Tøjstørrelse'.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/g, '');
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. But that didn't answer my question.

Comment: @tbsalling - you should probably edit the question, it is creating some confusion. You probably want to change the expected result to `T_jst_rrelse`. and what about `Tø_j`?